# Surjective function ?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, geometry, differential-geometry

It is a common fact that if $t \mapsto (f(t),g(t)) $ is a $C^1$ map from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]^2$ then it can not be surjective. Does it remain true if $f \in C^1$ and $g \in C^0$ ?

I was not able to find any counter example, but I'm not sure this is true ...

Answer (score 1):

Note that since $f\in C^1$, for almost all $x\in [0,1]$, there are only finitely many $t$ with $f(t)=x$ and that for every such $x$, the line $\{x\}\times[0,1]$ is certainly not covered by the curve.

Comment: Why f \in C^1 for almost every $x\in [0,1]$ ? We can find continuous functions nowhere differentiable

Comment: @M.LTA Does not the question read "Does it remain true if $f\in C^1$..."? Also the structure of the sentence is "Since .., {for almost... there are...}", not {Since... ,for almost...}, there are...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a partial solution with $g$ differentiable. 
If $Z= \{x,g'(x)=0\}$ the Sard lemma told us that $\lambda (g(Z))=0$ where $\lambda$ is the lebesgue measure.
Then for every $x\in [0,1]$ we have that $B(x)=\{t \in [0,1], x=g(t)\}$ is countable if $x \notin g(Z)$
If we denote by $A$ the arc, by the Fubini theorem we get : 
$$\lambda(A)=\int_{g([0,1])}\left(  \int_{f([0,1])} 1_A(x,y) \mathrm{d}y \right) \mathrm{d}x = \int_{x \notin g(Z)} \left( \int_{f(B(x))} 1_A(x,y) \mathrm{d}y \right) \mathrm{d}x =0$$